MX Master 3s extra buttons not recognized by Windows 11
I recently got a new laptop, a Lenovo E16 if it matters, when I connect my mx master 3s to it. Windows 11 only recognizes the left and right click, and middle scroll wheel. I have Logitech Options downloaded and have the extra buttons (Forward/Back, thumb, and thumb scroll wheel) set to custom uses in the Options program. However they don't work in any software whether the program I am using is Chrome, or windows file explorer. Doesn't matter, I've tried to download 3rd party button mapping software. However they fail to recognize that the extra buttons exist on the mouse. On other computers I have that are running windows 11 the extra buttons and Logitech Options work perfectly. Just not on my new laptop. Is there a why I can get windows to see the buttons or hard reset the mouse. I've had it for the last 5 years and never had an issue until the new laptop.
